# HttpClient Accept header doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api, client

I have been working with ASP API from my WinForm application. It was working fine but then I have started playing with namespaces and it started to write

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Product'
>   from content with media type 'text/html'.

I have created new solution, copied all the code but it is still not working. The response format is text/html although curl command with the same header(Accept application/json) is working fine.

This is my method for GETing product from API

```
public static async Task<ProductWithBool> GetProductByIdAsync(string id)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://eshop.ApiUpdatercentrum.tumam.cz/api/byznys/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Product product = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("GetProduct?code=" + id);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorManager.AddError("Getting product failed");
                return new ProductWithBool(null, 2);
            }
            if (product == null)
            {
                ErrorManager.AddError("Product not found");
                return new ProductWithBool(null, 1);
            }
            return new ProductWithBool(product, 0);
        }
```

Comment: That your application *accepts* json doesn't mean the server will *return* json. The problem is in the API, not in the code you posted

Answer (score 0):

Set this for your response before reading the content:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Side-note: By the way, I created this many moons ago to avoid unnecessarily killing and re-instantiating the HttpClient in different areas of the application. It has never failed me and it's made communicating with any rest service cleaner across my application. This gives me more flexibility as to when I want to end the HttpClient connection and dynamically control types of objects I parse from the result. Hopefully it helps you too.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Foo
{
    public class RestService : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed = false;
        private HttpClient _client;

        public RestService()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
            _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        }

        public async Task<T> GetRequest<T>(string queryURL)
        {
            T result = default(T);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync(queryURL).Result)
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        result = await content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (_client != null)
                    {
                        _client.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is a test of your API endpoint using the RestService class from above. It is working for me, I get JSON data back from the API. Note I had to add the Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SOTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (RestService rs = new RestService())
            {
                var result = rs.GetRequest<Product>(@"http://eshop.sambacentrum.tumam.cz/api/byznys/GetProduct?code=sup100").Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string CodeEAN { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string PriceWithTax { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class RestService : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed = false;
        private HttpClient _client;

        public RestService()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
            _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        }

        public async Task<T> GetRequest<T>(string queryURL)
        {
            T result = default(T);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync(queryURL).Result)
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        result = await content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (_client != null)
                    {
                        _client.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returned <null> and I get Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Comment: Sounds like it is not returning valid JSON back from that API.

Comment: Well, it is working by default with XML but with Accept header, it is returning JSON. I have tried cron and browser and both work just fine. The only problem is with the c# app-

Comment: [link](http://eshop.sambacentrum.tumam.cz/api/byznys/GetProduct?code=sup100) this is get request from the api

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Try using my RestService class above. I'm using it and it returns your dataset in JSON just fine.
What does your `Product` class look like?

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. I have included code that demonstrates your API works.

Comment: Thank you.I have tried it, copied it all and it still do the same. I am starting to freak out.

Comment: My project is targeting .NET 4.5 (4.5.2 specifically, but should work on 4.5).
This is in my packages.config:
`<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />`
`<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />`